# Django 1.8 not using Jinja2 template engine

Tags: python, django, jinja2

I have followed the instructions on using jinja2 with django1.8. --->

```
#settings.py

TEMPLATES = [
    {

        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.jinja2.Jinja2',
        'DIRS': [
            normpath(join(DJANGO_ROOT, 'templates/jinja2')),
        ],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'environment': 'kuyuweb_dj_1_8.jinja2.environment',
        },
    },
    {

        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.i18n',
                'django.template.context_processors.media',
                'django.template.context_processors.static',
                'django.template.context_processors.tz',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
                'django.core.context_processors.request',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

I have a  .py file including environment -->

```
from django.contrib.staticfiles.storage import staticfiles_storage
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
from jinja2 import Environment


def environment(**options):
    env = Environment(**options)
    env.globals.update({
        'static': staticfiles_storage.url,
        'url': reverse,
    })
    return env
```

and in my application folder i have templates/jinja2 folder.
 I have created a simple view as:

```
def home(request):

    works = Work.objects.filter(publish=True).order_by('-created_at')[:8]

    return render(request, 'jinja2/home.html', {'works':works })
```

But for example when i try to use jinja2 template tag as `{{ loop.index }}` it does not work. `{{ forloop.counter }}` is still working.

Is there something that i miss?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The jinja templates for your app should be in `yourapp/jinja2`, not `yourapp/templates/jinja2`.

If the template is at `yourapp/jinja2/home.html`, then your `render` line should be

```
return render(request, 'home.html', {'works':works })
```

Comment: Also, don't forget to install jinja2.

Comment: @limelights I think jinja2 is already installed, otherwise `from jinja2 import Environment` would be failing.

Comment: it worked. But so why 'DIRS': [
            normpath(join(DJANGO_ROOT, 'templates/jinja2')), mentions templates/jinja2  insead of just jinja2 ?

Comment: The `DIRS` setting is for template directories *outside* of your app's directories. It is the `app_dirname` setting the [Jinja2 engine](https://github.com/django/django/blob/b2f6e421a332ce45cf0f1f2f6bd5962765a013f1/django/template/backends/jinja2.py#L19) which says that app templates should go in `yourapp/jinja2`. I'm not sure I would recommend using `join(DJANGO_ROOT, 'templates/jinja2')` for Jinja templates. If you then use `join(DJANGO_ROOT, 'templates')` for Django templates, then the Jinja templates could be loaded by the Django template loader.

Comment: One more thing - if all your templates are in jinja2 subdirectories in your app, then you can set `DIRS: [],` to keep your config as simple as possible.